# UITextView breaking line to early

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, uitextview

I'm struggling with a problem of how to maximize the content size of a UITextView. The short of it is that the text view breaks to a second line while visually there is still room to fit more characters.

If you check the image below. The red text box is set to 160px width. *I am using contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-8,-8,-8,-8);* to remove some of the default padding. However this doesn't so much **remove** the padding as it offsets the content area. And that content area never takes advantage of the full 160px.

The text box (in gray) shows text rendered with *NSString drawInRect*. Given the same 160px width it renders two extra characters.

Is there a property in UITextView that could remove all padding and use the full frame? Or a workaround? I've tried *contentSize* with no success.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UITextView` has padding that `NSString`'s drawing methods do not have. To my knowledge, you can't disable this padding. A workaround is to increase the frame of the view to account for this padding. It sucks, but there isn't an official method of getting around this.

On the other hand, why do you want to remove the padding in the first place? Apple has chosen this spacing after hours of experimentation and debate, to best optimises for touch screen devices. You would be much better off accepting their R&D efforts and embracing their padding choices.

If you are just looking to display multiple lines of text, without the need to have the text editable or selectable, then you can use a `UILabel` with `label.numberOfLines` set to `0`. `UILabel` does not have any inherent padding applied.